# A simpler proof for an equality regarding sums of absolute values

Tags: inequality, summation, absolute-value

### Question

Let $I$ be a set of indices, and for all $i \in I$, assume
$$0 \le {a_i},{b_i},{c_i},{u_i},{v_i} \le 1 \;,$$
with $u_i+v_i=1$.

Assume that $L$ is an upper bound on both ${\sum\nolimits_i {\left| {{a_i} - {c_i}} \right|} }$ and ${\sum\nolimits_i {\left| {{b_i} - {c_i}} \right|} }$.

If $d_i=u_ia_i+v_ib_i$ for all $i \in I$, find an upper bound for ${\sum\nolimits_i {\left| {{d_i} - {c_i}} \right|} }$.

### My proof that $2L$ is an upper bound:

Define:
$${m_i} = \min \left\{ {{a_i},{b_i}} \right\} \qquad {M_i} = \max \left\{ {{a_i},{b_i}} \right\} \;,$$
and note that ${m_i} \leqslant {d_i} \leqslant {M_i}$. Moreover, let
$${\varepsilon _i} = \max \left\{ {\left| {{a_i} - {c_i}} \right|,\left| {{b_i} - {c_i}} \right|} \right\} \;.$$
Then:
$$\left. \begin{gathered}
  \text{If } {d_i} \geqslant {c_i}\,\,\,\, \Rightarrow \,\,\,\,\,\left| {{d_i} - {c_i}} \right| = {d_i} - {c_i} \leqslant {M_i} - {c_i} \leqslant \left| {{M_i} - {c_i}} \right| \leqslant {\varepsilon _i}\\
  \text{If } {d_i} < {c_i}\,\,\,\, \Rightarrow \,\,\,\,\,\left| {{d_i} - {c_i}} \right| = {c_i} - {d_i} \leqslant {c_i} - {m_i} \leqslant \left| {{c_i} - {m_i}} \right| \leqslant {\varepsilon _i}\\ 
\end{gathered}  \right\} \Rightarrow \,\left| {{d_i} - {c_i}} \right| \leqslant {\varepsilon _i} \;.$$

Therefore
$$\sum\nolimits_i {\left| {{d_i} - {c_i}} \right|}  \leqslant \sum\nolimits_i {{\varepsilon _i}}  \leqslant \sum\nolimits_i {\left( {\left| {{a_i} - {c_i}} \right| + \left| {{b_i} - {c_i}} \right|} \right)}  \leqslant 2L \;.$$

> Is there any simpler proof?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For every $i$, $d_i-c_i=u_i(a_i-c_i)+v_i(b_i-c_i)$ hence $$|d_i-c_i|\leqslant u_i|a_i-c_i|+v_i|b_i-c_i|\leqslant |a_i-c_i|+|b_i-c_i|.
$$
Summing this on $i$ yields 
$$
\sum\limits_i|d_i-c_i|\leqslant\sum\limits_i|a_i-c_i|+\sum\limits_i|b_i-c_i|\leqslant2L.
$$